# Why is redux State no updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Redux Action but I can´t make it work .
I need to find the index of an object which nested into an array of a firebase collection.
After getting the data from the DB, I calculate the index but can´t send it to redux.
It´s probably a super noob JavaScript mistake, I don´t know why but i can´t update the object that I am sending to redux (reDatos)

```js
export const calcularIdsAModificar = (MOid) => {
  let reDatos = {
    MOid: MOid,
    MOidindex: null,
  };

  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
    const Firestore = getFirestore();
    const authorId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
    let experienciasArray = 'sin datos';

    Firestore.collection('users')
      .doc(authorId)
      .get()
      .then((resp) => {
        experienciasArray = resp.data().experiencia;
        let newindex = experienciasArray.findIndex((expe) => expe.id === MOid);
        reDatos['MOidindex'] = newindex;
      })

      .then(dispatch({ type: 'ONCLICK_EDITAR_EXPERIENCIA', reDatos: reDatos }));
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you share your reducer as well?

Comment: try with switch case hope it will works:

 function Auth(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGN_UP_CALL:
      state = {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
      break;
 default:
      break;
  }
  return state;
}

Comment: The reducer seems to be working fine, because it updates correctly the state of MOid . The problem is that I don´t know how to update the object (reDatos.MOidindex) and then send it to redux reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem: the second `then` gets called imediatelly when the function is declared. For it to work, you need to pass handler (arrow function or funciton declaration) to the `then`.

Another thing to note here is that you don't actually need the second `then`. Since the code inside the first `then` is synchronous, you could call the dispatch inside it.

```
 return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {

       const Firestore = getFirestore();
       const authorId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
       let experienciasArray = 'sin datos'
      
       

       Firestore.collection('users').doc(authorId).get().then(resp =>  {
           
        experienciasArray = resp.data().experiencia          
        let newindex = experienciasArray.findIndex(expe => expe.id === MOid)
        reDatos['MOidindex'] = newindex

        dispatch({ type:'ONCLICK_EDITAR_EXPERIENCIA', reDatos: reDatos })    

       });
      
        //.then(() =>  {dispatch...}); //Or call a dispatch inside an arrow function here.  

    }
```